# How to get the path of the posted file in Python

Tags: python, django

I am getting a file posting from a file:

```
file = request.post['ufile']
```

I want to get the path. How can I get it?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the [`request.FILES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) dictionary.

Check out the [official documentation about the `UploadedFile` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile.temporary_file_path), you can use the `UploadedFile.temporary_file_path` attribute, but beware that only files uploaded to disk expose it (that is, normally, when using the `TemporaryFileUploadHandler` uploads handler).

```
upload = request.FILES['ufile']
path = upload.temporary_file_path
```

In the normal case, though, you would like to use the file handler directly:

```
upload = request.FILES['ufile']
content = upload.read()  # For small files
# ... or ...
for chunk in upload.chunks():
    do_somthing_with_chunk(chunk)  # For bigger files
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `request.FILES['ufile'].file.name`

you will get like this `/var/folders/v7/1dtcydw51_s1ydkmypx1fggh0000gn/T/tmpKGp4mX.upload`

and use `file.name`, your upload file have to bigger than 2.5M.

if you want to change this , see [File Upload Settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#file-upload-settings)

Answer (score 1):

We cannot get the file path from the post request, only the filename, because flask doesn't has the file system access. If you need to get the file and perform some operations on it then you can try creating a temp directory save the file there, you can also get the path.

```
import tempfile
import shutil

dirpath = tempfile.mkdtemp()
# perform some operations if needed
shutil.rmtree(dirpath) # remove the  temp directory
```